# Move sprite in a specific angle

Tags: c#, xna, angle, trigonometry

In my XNA game, I can rotate my sprite with the A and the D keys, everything works well. But to my problem:

How do I calculate the X and Y to move the sprite in which direction the sprite is angled, I have this:

```
 float x = (float)Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(getRotation()));
 float y = (float)Math.Sin(MathHelper.ToRadians(getRotation()));
```

but that's not working at all. I want to move my sprite like +4 pixels every time you hold the W key.

Comment: @Machinegon The sprite's shape is irrelevant.  Moving the sprite is an operation that relies only on the current location and facing.  Sprite shape is only important when doing collision detection.

Comment: Misread that question, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

Almost there:

```
sprite.x += ( float ) ( Math.Cos( MathHelper.ToRadians( getRotation( ) ) ) * speedX );
sprite.y += ( float ) ( Math.Sin( MathHelper.ToRadians( getRotation( ) ) ) * speedY );
```

Comment: @user1568364 it depends on getRotation(). If it moves only in the same direction probably there's something wrong there

Comment: the rotation is just a plain float, i draw the sprite using batch.Draw(texture, position, sourceRectangle, Color.White, rotation,new Vector2(texture.Width/2,texture.Height/2),1.0f,SpriteEffects.None,1); where rotation is again just a plain float variable.

Comment: @user1568364 if you are really sure that the rotation is correct the only other thing that pops out of my mind is about speedY. It is greater than 0 isn't it? ;)

Comment: hmm... Ofcourse when if i print the rotation, it goes like 0.0f is the regular angle, and 1,5f is 45 degrees the convertToRadians method seems to be converting degrees to radians, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @user1568364 as a rule of thumb, 0 degree are 0 radians, 90 degree are  1.57 radians, 180 degree are 3.14 radians and 270 are 4.71 radians

Answer (score 0):

As @BlackBear pointed out, you have to multiply the rotation by the distance you want to move.

When you're working with this sort of thing it helps to have a point (or vector) class that encapsulates the basics - addition, scaling, rotation, angle determination, etc. - and to visualize movement in terms of vectors.

Given a functional Point2D class for instance:

```
// define movement vector as +4 units in 'Y' axis
// rotated by player facing
Point2D MoveVector = new Point2D(0, 4).Rotate(Player.FacingAngle);

// adjust player position by movement vector:
Player.Position.Add(MoveVector);
```

A better idea might be to have the player contain a direction vector that can be used whenever facing is required to be mapped to 2D coordinates.  Movement then becomes:

```
Player.Position.Add(Player.FacingVector * MoveSpeed);
```

This is handy for things like spawning bullets and the like, since you can set their initial facing vector to the player's facing vector and so on, saving on rotation operations all down the chain.

And you get the added bonus that your code gets a bit more self-documenting :P

**Edit - a bunch of code:**

Here's part of my Point2D implementation:

```
public class Point2D
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    public Point2D(double X = 0, double Y = 0)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    // update this Point2D by adding other
    public Point2D AddEquals(Point2D other)
    {
        X += other.X;
        Y += other.Y;
        return this;
    }

    // return a new Point2D that is the sum of this and other
    public Point2D Add(Point2D other)
    {
        return new Point2D(X + other.X, Y + other.Y);
    }

    public Point2D Multiply(double scalar)
    {
        return new Point2D(X * scalar, Y * scalar);
    }

    // rotate by angle (in radians)
    public Point2D Rotate(double angle)
    {
        double c = Math.cos(angle), s = Math.sin(angle);
        double rx = X * s - Y * c;
        double ry = Y * s + X * c;
        return new Point2D(rx, ry);
    }

    public Point2D RotateDegrees(double angle)
    {
        return Rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    public double Distance(Point2D other)
    {
        double dx = other.X - X, dy = other.Y - Y;
        return Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
}
```

You can flesh out the other operations.  Those ones are enough for this code:

```
public class Player
{
    public Point2D location;
    // facing angle in degrees
    public double facing;

    public void TurnLeft(double degrees)
    {
        facing = (facing + 360 - degrees) % 360;
    }

    public void TurnRight(double degrees)
    {
        facing = (facing + degrees) % 360;
    }

    public void MoveForward(double distance)
    {
        // calculate movement vector
        Point2D move = new Point2D(0, distance).RotateDegrees(facing);

        // add to position
        this.location.AddEquals(move);
    }
}
```

The naming is a bit clumsy in places, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Okay, I'm having trouble.. I really can't get it to work at all. The sprite is just moving left or teleports to the left upper corner when i press W... :(

Comment: This answer is bad advice. Math might be ok, but it is bad practice to implement your own classes for things that already exist, and also using doubles is not something one usually does in game development.

Comment: @Stig-RuneSkansgård - I came from a C++ background, from the good old days before the STL and BOOST made things easy.  I'm in the habit of developing such things for myself... and I much prefer double-precision for accuracy rather than the limited precision of the floats used by the `Vector2` class.

Comment: @Corey - While you may prefer double precision, we never, or at least very rarely, use that in game development in C++ either. This is because most CPUs are REALLY good at floats, and not as good with doubles. Though this might not be such a big deal nowadays, working with 64bit CPUs, you still have to use floats on the GPU, so still; Better to use floats. The lack of precision in float is not something you would normally notice unless you work with large/small numbers. Scaling usually lets you avoid problems with that :)

Comment: Also; XNA's math is generally faster than what you would make yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Define what is forward when rotation is 0.
var forward = new Vector2(1f,0f);

//Create a rotation-matrix that can rotate the forward-vector
var rotater = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(getRotation()));

//rotate and normalize vector (normalizing makes the length = 1)
forward = Vector2.TransformNormal(forward, rotater);

//move in rotated forward direction times 4
Position += forward * 4f;
```

but I would suggest using a pixels-per-second value and multiplying with deltatime:

```
Position += forward * pixelsPerSecond * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```